# C++ array with randomly placed 1s

Tags: c++

With C++, I'm trying to create an array of size 10201, with 50 1s randomly placed and zeros everywhere else. 
I'm sure its simple but I'm new to C++!! 
Thanks.

Comment: Is it the specific array size you are having difficulty with?

Comment: No, I thought to try 
int array[10201]={[0...10200]=0};
to get the zeros but I'm not sure how to assign the 1s randomly.

Comment: The part between `{` and `}` is not C++ syntax.

Comment: Run in a loop 50 times, call rand() % 10201, and use the result as the index of the 1. Check if it's already 1 before to avoid duplicate indices

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple.

Initialize the array with 50 1s on the first positions and the rest with 0s. Then use  [<del>std::random_shuffle</del> std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) on the whole array.